# Error "was not declared in this scope" when importing .ui file into Qt5 C++

Tags: c++, qt

I met an error " was not declared in this scope" when importing Qt Wizard from Qt Designer into Qt C++ application.

`src/main.cpp`

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "new_conference_wizard.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    NewConferenceWizard *conf = new NewConferenceWizard;
    conf->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

`src/new_conference_wizard.cpp`

```
#include "new_conference_wizard.h"

NewConferenceWizard::NewConferenceWizard(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::NewConferenceWizard) {
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

NewConferenceWizard::~NewConferenceWizard()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

`src/new_conference_wizard.h`

```
#ifdef NEW_CONFERENCE_WIZARD_H
#define NEW_CONFERENCE_WIZARD_H

#include <QWizard>
#include "ui_new_conference_wizard.h"

namespace Ui {
class NewConferenceWizard;
}

class NewConferenceWizard : public QWizard
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit NewConferenceWizard(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~NewConferenceWizard();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};


#endif
```

All files in source code (I only keep the important files for debuging): https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rR4H9Na3bCvdyREn_GZjoDUs9lc3ieYi

**Compiler Output:**

```
...
/mnt/DATA/Sync2/WorkData/HUST2019/Projects/NetworkAndMedia/Project/desktop-app/src/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/mnt/DATA/Sync2/WorkData/HUST2019/Projects/NetworkAndMedia/Project/desktop-app/src/main.cpp:36:5: error: ‘NewConferenceWizard’ was not declared in this scope
     NewConferenceWizard *conf = new NewConferenceWizard;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/mnt/DATA/Sync2/WorkData/HUST2019/Projects/NetworkAndMedia/Project/desktop-app/src/main.cpp:36:26: error: ‘conf’ was not declared in this scope
     NewConferenceWizard *conf = new NewConferenceWizard;
                          ^~~~
/mnt/DATA/Sync2/WorkData/HUST2019/Projects/NetworkAndMedia/Project/desktop-app/src/main.cpp:36:26: note: suggested alternative: ‘cosf’
     NewConferenceWizard *conf = new NewConferenceWizard;
                          ^~~~
                          cosf
/mnt/DATA/Sync2/WorkData/HUST2019/Projects/NetworkAndMedia/Project/desktop-app/src/main.cpp:36:37: error: ‘NewConferenceWizard’ does not name a type
     NewConferenceWizard *conf = new NewConferenceWizard;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your header file, `#ifdef NEW_CONFERENCE_WIZARD_H` should be opposite condition:

```
#ifndef NEW_CONFERENCE_WIZARD_H
```

With your typo, the file contents are never included in the compilation, and thus `main.c` does not have the declarations there.